# Can we have any Blackout dates using JQuery UI Datepicker plugin on ASP.NET MVC Page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-2

I am wondering if we can have block any specific dates from Jquery UI DatePicker?

For Example, if we want to block all dates till tomorrow, we specify as below.

```
 $("#UsageDate").datepicker({ minDate: +1 });
```

Similarly, I want to block Weekends and few official days from my Holidays Schedule(For example, May 31, Nov 27th and Dec 25th).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see an example of doing this here:
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerCustomCellRender.html